# Manipulator label issue

Tags: manipulate

Here is a small prototype construct mimicking a more complex manipulate environment I am trying to build:

```
t = AbsoluteTime[];
Manipulate[nd, {{nd, 30, "Data included up to:"}, 24, 30, 1, 
  Labeled[Manipulator[##], 
    DateObject[t - 86400 (30 - nd), "Day", 
     DateFormat -> {"MonthName", " ", "Day", ", ", "Year"}]] &}]
```

So I want to have a slider moving in increments corresponding to single days (in a time series that has dates in it), and I want the control to show the date corresponding to these steps. The above construct *kind of* works, but there is the issue that I cannot drag the slider by more than one stop. After I have moved it by one stop, I need to let go, move the mouse away from the slider, pick it back up and move again.

In contrast, if I just do something like

```
t = AbsoluteTime[];
Manipulate[nd, {{nd, 30, "Data included up to:"}, 24, 30, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Then I can continue to move the slider if I just keep dragging, but I don't get a date displayed by the control.

Does anyone know what goes wrong in my first example? Any suggestion of an alternative way to get a properly formatted date label?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
t = AbsoluteTime[];

Manipulate[nd, 
 Column[{Control@{{nd, 30, "Data included up to:"}, 24, 30, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
   Dynamic @ DateObject[t - 86400 (30 - nd), "Day", 
      DateFormat -> {"MonthName", " ", "Day", ", ", "Year"}]}, 
  Alignment -> Center]]
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent, thanks very much!